# DNS Validation fail

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, internal-dns

I'm running a DNS server and an outer-webserver on the same computer, which means the same external and internal IP's.

I've checked them with tools.pingdom.com and these:

http://www.intodns.com/u4ik.us
http://www.intodns.com/www.u4ik.us

And although nobody has any problems accessing my site, some parts of the test fail.

Besides the "too few nameservers" part, I need help with these:

"Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers" I have no clue how to fix this...

"WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records." Likely because I've only got ns1 running now.

Any help, and I'm forever thankful.

Comment: I can't add comments but as an added solution you may want to use DNSStuff.com for troubleshooting pretty much any DNS or Web tech. Its worth the annual subscription if you plan to administer your own internal web farm and name server. They may even provide some good free tools but its been a while since I looked at the free only. Much more detailed set of checks than Pingdom and others provide IMO. Brent

Comment: What is the domain name in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nameservers needed to be defined in two places: as glue records in your top-level-domain (something your registrar handles, and already has) and NS records in the zone files hosted on your DNS server.

You appear need to be missing the latter.

Check your DNS servers documentation on how to add them.

If you're running Simple DNS Plus (as fpdns seems to think), you can find that documentation at http://www.simpledns.com/help/v52/rec_ns.htm.